# Class with nested association to itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I have a class with a nested association to itself:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_gateways
  has_many :gateways, through: :location_gateways, class_name: "Location", :dependent => :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gateways, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to :location, optional: true
end
```

The connecting model:

```
class LocationGateway < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, :class_name => "Location"
  belongs_to :gateway, :class_name => "Location"
end
```

Now I would like to make a form that can create a Location and some gateways but I get an `Gateway must exist` error when I submit it (the call to `Location.new`)

I'm assuming this is because the model `Gateway` doesn't exist. How can I make rails understand that it should create another `Location`and not a `Gateway`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found no way around this error. I had to make a new class `Gateway` that inherits from `Location` and add a `type` to Locations (STI).